# IP address of customer in Magento

Tags: magento

I Want IP address from which the user is viewing the current page

and i m using

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

and it show me `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Are you running the server on localhost?

Comment: yes i am running the server on localhost

Comment: Then is it not showing the expected IP?

Comment: that display `127.0.0.1` which is not my ip

Comment: Joking apart, 127.0.0.1 is the standard IP address for [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). Why do you think it's been showing wrong?

Comment: @JürgenThelen plz give it as a answer and i will accept it thnx...:)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a Magento function to get customer's IP Address:

```
echo Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
```

`getRemoteAddr()` also accepts a boolean parameter.  When `false` (default) it will return the IP address as a string in the common dotted-decimal notation (e.g. 192.168.0.1).  When `true` it will return the IP in its decimal notation--a 32-bit integer.  See [IPv4 Address Representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations) to understand the formats.

Comment: why you have added `true`? it returns `ip2long`. is there any advantage of that?

Comment: Magento integrators should note the `//remote_addr_headers` field in app/etc/local.xml.additional for getting the correct client address when a reverse proxy or load balancer is between the client and origin web server.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal using IP addresses in their 32bit format is fairly rare.  It's useful as a datatype in systems that don't have "real" IP support (e.g. an `int` in a database is much better than a `varchar`)

Answer (score 1):

When Magento (server) and the browser (client) are both on your computer (`localhost`), then it's *not* an error, but correct that PHP's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains `127.0.0.1` (or `::1`).

This is because 127.0.0.1 is the standard IPv4 loopback address for any `localhost`.

See section "3. Global and Other Specialized Address Blocks" of [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host. This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one: `Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();`

This will return ip address such as '127.0.0.1'

When you use `Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(true);` it will return long (2130706433)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the machine behind a proxy it is better to use this kind of code:

$ips = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
$ip =trim($ips[count($ips) - 1]);